# How to make shiny group checkbox not reactive

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny, reactive

I am building an app in shiny where user chooses conditions for analysis and also can filter data before analysis. So whenever he changes the dataset he also needs to reassign the checkboxgroup and it is a bit annoying. Is there a way to store the checkboxes values or make them not reactive?

Answer (score 1):

`isolate` is the tool for that. If your checkbox id is `checkbox`, then you can access its value by calling `input$checkbox`, and restrict automatic updating of its dependend outputs by wrapping that into `isolate(input$checkbox)`.